# Displaying main screen to old user and an info screen to a new user before the main screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have a main screen that I want to display straight away to an old user of the app (Meaning token has been set) but to a new user, I want to display a column with some information etc. first and after the user presses the button it will open the main screen. However, the below code doesn't work as I wish (this doesn't change the view in any way). What would be the correct approach to this problem?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getPrefs(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if(token == null){
              return Column(
                verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      return mainScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );

            }
            else{
              return mainScreen();
            }

          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
    );
```

```
  Widget mainScreen(){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Feed planner',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        ),
        toolbarHeight: 50,
        actions: [

          IconButton(icon: icon, onPressed: _pushSettings),
        ],
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: _buildGrid()),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1, after OP provided more info:

Make your homescreen widget like this:

```
Widget mainScreen(bool token){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Feed planner',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        ),
        toolbarHeight: 50,
        actions: [

          IconButton(icon: icon, onPressed: _pushSettings),
        ],
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            token == null ? Text('Add your text or widget here for new users') : Container()
            Expanded(child: _buildGrid()),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

And your Future builder like this:

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getPrefs(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return mainScreen(snapshot); //or the token you are getting
            }
           else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        })
```

The problem is here:

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: (){
  return mainScreen();
 },
)
```

You should use:

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: (){
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mainScreen'); //or whatever the name of your home screen is in routes.
 },
)
```

Comment: MainScreen is a widget inside the same class as the build function. Should I rearrange my project to match this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics type of handling of screens. I am new to flutter so correct and efficient way of building applications is not natural for me yet

Comment: Hello @Adventune, if you want the short answer, then yes. Following the documentation is always advised. And from there [the link you pseted], is a good start to know how the look and feel of organized routing is. But for your current structure, you can move the token check into homescreen, and inside homescreen widget, if there is no token, display your message. I'll update my answer with an example, check it out in a few minutes.